# Shift left register with load and enable signals

Tags: vhdl

I'm making a program that shifts the contents of a 4 bit binary register to the left. If I have as an input 0101, it will give 1010.

Expected working:

- If ENABLE is '1' and LOAD is '1' it should read from data_in and charge the values into aux. But not shift.
- If ENABLE is '1' and LOAD is '0' it should shift to the left the values of the aux variable.
- If ENABLE is '0' it doesn't do anything.

Actual result:
Everything works fine except when ENABLE is '1' and LOAD is '0', it does not shift the values.

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all; 
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
ENTITY shift_left IS
    GENERIC (num_bits:POSITIVE:= 4);
      PORT (
       clk:                 IN STD_LOGIC;
       enable:              IN STD_LOGIC;
       load:                IN STD_LOGIC;
      data_in:              IN UNSIGNED  (num_bits -1  DOWNTO 0); 
      data_out:         OUT UNSIGNED (num_bits -1  DOWNTO 0)); 
END shift_left;


ARCHITECTURE behaviour OF shift_left IS 
BEGIN
    PROCESS 

    variable aux: UNSIGNED(num_bits-1 downto 0);
    BEGIN
        WAIT UNTIL RISING_EDGE (clk);
            IF enable = '1' THEN
                IF load = '1' THEN
                    aux := data_in; 
                ELSE
                    FOR i IN num_bits-2 TO 0 LOOP 
                        aux(i+1) := aux(i);
                    END LOOP;
                    aux(0) := '0';
                END IF;
            END IF;--  enable
            data_out <= aux;
    END PROCESS;
END behaviour;
```

Comment: How are you testing the code, as it appears ok to me.

Comment: Design, not program. Your entity/architecture doesn't by itself replicate the problem. It's not a [mcve]. IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2 Scalar types, 5.2.1 General para 4 (in part): "The range L to R is called an ascending range; if L > R, then the range is a null range." The subset of values specified by a null range is empty. (A typographical error in the for loop iteration scheme ,the reserved word `to` should be `downto`, i.e. `FOR i IN num_bits-2 DOWNTO 0 LOOP`. Another way of implementing the shift would be `aux := aux(num_bits - 2 downto 0) & '0';`.

Comment: @Tricky I'm using Quartus II with model sim plus a test program.